# How can I create a shell script shortcut?

Tags: linux, debian, shell-script

I'm using Debian and there's a user who has a script called **start.sh**. I want the user to be able to call the script by typing `application ...` instead of `./start.sh ...`

I've been playing with symbolic links to `/bin`, but I think there are better ways to do this, using PATH, or something else.

**Question:** What is the best practice for a shell script shortcut like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
alias application=/path/to/start.sh
```

Symlinking would work too.  Whether either of this is "best" practice depends on what you want to do.

Comment: Why does it depend? The behavior seems identical...

Comment: Wait... This only works until I close the shell!

Comment: @bytecode77 1) to make this "permannt" you need to put this in the shell startup file, eg $HOME/.bashrc or the like  2) An alias is a text substitution, it can do subtly different things than a normal invocation.

Comment: But then again, isn't it simpler to just symlink to `/bin`?

Comment: @bytecode77 if you're symlinking to /bin, you're almost surely Doing It Wrong.  Edit the shell startup file and add to PATH

Comment: I've seen your answer and commented on it.

Answer (score 1):

The canonical way to fix this is to add to the user's PATH variable.  How to do this depends on the shell used, but for most (non-Csh based shells) usually PATH=$PATH:/dir/that/script/is/in works.

Comment: How can I change `./start.sh ...` to `application ...` with this method?

Comment: @bytecode77 actually you cant.  the alias is the way to "rename" it, with some caveats.  why the name change needed?  you could have a local shell script in your PATH that is names application  i do this all the time, for specific reasons

Comment: Does this also work for crontabs?